# In laravel how to get the variables from a string saved in db inside {{}}?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get all the variables saved in DB string with the html tags.

I want:

I have a paragraph saved in DB with the variables like `{{$username}}`.

I want to fetch all the variables from the string which is saved in DB.

Something like only finds in between {{ and }} (braces) and get the variable.

> I have tried:

```
`preg_match('/(\{{(.*?)\}})/', $request->content, $matches);`
```

It is giving me the only first variable not all. I want all of them.

Comment: mayby this regex: \{(.*?)\}}, can help you

Comment: @first, can you give me the full regex plaease.

Comment: ```$str = '{{$username}}The rain in SPAIN falls mainly on the{{$password}} plains.{{$email}}';
        $pattern = "/\{{(.*?)\}}/i";
        if(preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches)) {
            dd($matches);
        }```

Comment: @first, It works Thank you can you post this as the answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$str = '{{$username}}The rain in SPAIN falls mainly on the{{$password}} plains.{{$email}}';         $pattern = "/\{{(.*?)\}}/i";         

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches)) {
    dd($matches);        
}
```